# sd_bus_add_match return value of callback

Tags: c, dbus, systemd

I'm using `sd_bus_add_match` from libsystemd to register a slot. The [doc](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/sd_bus_add_match.html) says:

> If an error occurs during the callback invocation, the callback should return a negative error number. If it wants other callbacks that match the same rule to be called, it should return 0. Otherwise it should return a positive integer.

But how is it intended to use this return value? All examples I've found so far `return 0;` from the callback.